# Padding according to screen

Tags: html, css, padding

i created whole site and when i opened it in another sized monitor its mess.

I have menu with lot of divs, one div is like one button, and i want to do padding so they have space between them but without use of pixels, how to do that?

Thanks a lot guys!

```
#menu {
width: 62%;
height: 40px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 19%;
border: 1px solid #484848;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 30px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
background-color: #484848;
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages for the padding as well. Should be fine.

Comment: What about font size? Font size to fit screen size?

Comment: padding and font-size arent remotely related to each other.

Comment: I found for text 'vh'. Last thing is images, how to set image width and height according to screen size? THANKS FOR ANSWERS BTW, you helped me lot already!

Comment: No prob @AleksandarMakragic. happy to help. Take a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units.